# UIImageView will scale instead of rotation if moved , iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation

hy

i want to make a little animation.the rotation works fine if the image is static.
but when i move my image view it will stretch the image. the image can be moved 
whit out a problem if it's not rotated.

```
-(void)play
{

        CGRect ship=image.frame;
        ship.origin.x=ship.origin.x+move;
        ship.origin.y=ship.origin.y+move2;
        image.frame=ship;
}

-(void)rotate 
{
       int degre=180;
       float radian=degre*(3.14/180);
       image.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radian); 
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? `CGRect ship=image` looks suspicious. - And use `M_PI` instead of `3.14` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the transform property you are not allowed to change the position by changing the frame, you have to use the center property.

So this should help:

```
-(void)play
{
    image.center=CGPointMake(image.center.x + move, image.center.y + move2);
}
```

Comment: ship does not have a variable center and if i try in image it can't be manipulated directly... wrote to fast

Comment: works but it centers the image in the middle of the screen and it stays there

Comment: You just interrupted my 2 days of research and understanding why my rotated items could not move, thanks !!!